# How to set the location a Dojo Dialog opens at?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dialog, location

I have a Dojo dialog that is opened when a user clicks on an element on the page.

I want control the location it opens at ....really I want it to open beside (relative to) the other dom element clicked on.

But I can seem to figure out how to do either of the above.

Thank for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take a loot at the `Tooltip` doc for Dojo. I've never had experience with Dojo, but here are some links that should help you get started.

[Dojo Dijit Dialog relative position. is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469397/dojo-dijit-dialog-relative-position-is-it-possible)

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/TooltipDialog

http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2011-May/054581.html

Comment: Thanks ... using dojo.position got me location of the clicked on element and I could set the top and left.

Answer (score 2):

Open an dialog with dojo relative to click position:

```
dojo.style(pointDialog.domNode, 'visibility', 'hidden');
pointDialog.show().then(function () {
    dojo.style(pointDialog.domNode, 'top', clickEvt.pageY);
    dojo.style(pointDialog.domNode, 'visibility', 'visible');
});
```

The visibility trick is needed for dialog not hop

Comment: If you're on dojo 1.7+ (currently 1.9) you should use `domStyle.set("someNode", "width", "100px");` with `"dojo/dom-style"`

Comment: One issue is that resizing the window will cause a snapback to the original (center) position. To fix this, call `dialog._endDrag();`  after `domStyle.set(..., "top");` where dialog is the dijit object