# How to position ExtLib dialog in XPages not to center parent or screen

Tags: css, xpages

I want to position my Extension Lib Dialog control to another than it´s default position, which seems to center to the window or the parent element. I have seen that there is a resize-listener, maybe this could be overwritten.

I tried to position it directly in the style-class, no success:

```html
<xe:dialog id="loginDialog">
  <xe:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:return "top:100px !important; left:50px !important;";}]]></xe:this.style>
  <xp:div>
 <xp:label value="Label" id="label1"></xp:label>
  </xp:div>
</xe:dialog>
```

Seems that no one else has this problem ?? I could not find any topics or posts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want a dialog?  You might want to check out the ToolTip and Tooltip dialog controls.  That's likely what you want instead of trying to mess with the main dialog.
The Ext. Library comes with a sample  application.  There should be code examples in there.  Suggest you take a look at this page once you get it installed : /XPagesExt.nsf/Core_InPlaceDialog.xsp

If you must mess with the dialog itself - search for ways to do this with a standard dojo dialog.  Since that's where the XPages one comes from.  Maybe start here :  [How to set the location a Dojo Dialog opens at?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076804/how-to-set-the-location-a-dojo-dialog-opens-at)

Comment: Hi David ! 
Thank you for your advices...I tried the Core_InPlaceDialog.xsp, they all pop up screen-centered.
What I want to do: display a logon form in a way of a dialog ("popup-style")

Comment: Are you sure?  From my taking a quick look <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.openTooltipDialog('#{id:tooltipDialog1}','#{id:computedField1}')]]></xp:this.script>   binds it to the field so it's not centered on the page at all.  It's calling <xe:tooltipDialog>  Make sure you're looking at "Edit - Tooltip" and not "Edit - Modal".  the model DOES center and the tooltip dialog does not.

Comment: David, thank you very much for your answer ! I did not know the openTooltipDialog function.
Now it is positioned to its given element id, although I think that I have to add the cancel button and some close icon myself. Sure, it´s only a tooltip....

Comment: Glad it's working.  the example that comes with the project does have an ok and cancel button if you need to see how that's done.